# missing default value for NOT NULL TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I want to execute the following mysql statement from the framadate software.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sondage` (
  `id_sondage` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `commentaires` text,
  `mail_admin` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom_admin` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titre` text,
  `id_sondage_admin` char(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_creation` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_fin` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `format` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailsonde` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `statut` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = actif ; 0 = inactif ; ',
  UNIQUE KEY `id_sondage` (`id_sondage`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

But I get the error: `Error in query (1067): Invalid default value for 'date_fin'`
I wonder what that means, because there is no default value given for date_fin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your MySQL server is insisting you provide a default value for your `date_fin` column.  Try this.

```
    ...
    `date_fin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
    ...
```

In general, it's a reasonably good practice to provide default values for `NOT NULL` columns.